# replace everything up to the last hyphen in android

Tags: android, replace

How is it possible to replace everything of the string `20-30-55`, so that I can get `55`?

I tried `var.replace("\\*-",""))` but it didn't work.

I just need this in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you should look at the `.split()` function on a `String`. If you use

```
String arr[] = s.split("x");
```

then it will return you an array of all the bits of `s`, using `x` as the expression to use for splitting it up.

In your case, if you split on a hyphen, and look at the last element of the array, it'll give what you need.

You could also get what you want with

```
s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("-")+1);
```

This finds the last occurrence of a hyphen, and gives you the rest of the `String` from just after that point through to the end.